# PHP JSP Curl: Issue- Invalid Token

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to make a login session to a JSP file using PHP and Curl.

I am getting an error for `invalid token`

```
$data_string = json_encode($curl_post_data); 

$service_url = 'http://zxczxczczxc.jsp';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);      
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "ZHJlZGR5:QnJzbm5yczY4Iw==");       
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json;charset ="utf-8"','Authorization: Basic xcxc:xcxc== Token zxcxzc='));
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($curl_response);
$result = json_decode($curl_response);      
//print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl));      
//echo '</pre>';
curl_close($curl);
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error?